# I am trying to get the user id which is created automatically

Tags: php, sql

```
$sql4 = "SELECT userid, userName FROM $user_table WHERE userName= '$userNames'";
$result = $conn->query($sql4);
$_SESSION['myUser'] = $result['userid'] ;
```

I have most code I can find but nothing works

Comment: After a Query you have to FETCH the result(s) see the PHP Manual

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming these lines of code come immediately after executing an insert of a new user record and you are using PDO. You could try:

```
$last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
$_SESSION['myUser'] = $last_id;
```

Comment: OP does not actually state that they have just created a new user, so this may not really be what thay are after

Comment: @RiggsFolly OP implied as much in the subject line "... created automatically"